# Use of Poster attribute in video shows Video Jump Back on load

Tags: html5-video

`< video poster="Some URL">
</video>`

This is basic implementation in code. But when I refresh the page, I see poster image first, then in fraction of seconds I see actual video jumping back. Which creates jump back and forth like visual.
Any suggestions on fixing this?

Comment: Animated opacity (fade-in) via CSS for the element could help?

Comment: did you solve this?